# Notification implementation in react native app

Tags: react-native-firebase, react-native-notifications

i want that if user fill the customer register form in that if they select date and time so, on that selected date and time they will receive the notification with the data they fill and the condition is that if user is not logged in or app is close they didn't see the notification only when he is logged in they will see the notification and this notification also visible on the admin panel on the website

Provide the steps that how to implement that feature in my app

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.